# How to fix Shared filesystem configuration in wso2 am 2.6 active-active all-in-one implement

Tags: configuration, wso2, filesystems, shared, microsoft-distributed-file-system

I have 2 servers of wso2 api-m with deployment of active-active all in one. I am using [link](https://docs.wso2.com/display/AM260/Configuring+an+Active-Active+Deployment#ConfiguringanActive-ActiveDeployment-step1) for configuring.
In part 4 and 5, I use DFS instead of rsync and shared path : 'wso2-am-2.6.0\repository\deployment\server' in both servers in both directions. And I do what part 5 said exactly to my servers(changed the serverUrl of  in api-manager.xml in both servers to server1's IP). And I uses ARR on my local system for loadbalancer.
After I run my both servers, when create an API, even in both servers' log show that the API created, but they don't sync and if I off the real server that API created on it, I can not see the API in another server's publisher.
can anyone tell what part I go wrong??

Comment: Just a note: rsync or shared mount is specifically about APIM's gateway component. If you see that the API creation log, that means gateway received the newly published API, and is ready to serve requests from both servers. Can you explain more what you mean when you say "they don't sync"?

Comment: Yes, exactly this happens,but when I open publisher and store of server1 I Can not see server2 created APIs!

Comment: Does the APIs become visible when you restart both nodes? If not, it is possible that your registry mounting configuration (via registry.xml and master-datasources.xml) in one node is busted. You can check whether both are connecting to the same db, and mounting is correct. In addition, you do not need to set the serverUrl of in api-manager.xml in both servers to server1's IP because you are using a shared file mount, not a one-way file sharing method like rsync.